# How to display PHP output in a table?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get my php output to display into a table. However, I get a error message each time.

**Code without table:**

```
 Print "<strong>Responsibility: $<strong> ";
 Print  number_format($RunningTotal,2);
```

**Code with table which I get a error message:**

```
Print "<TABLE><tr><td width = '50 px'>Responsibility: $<strong></td> ";
Print "<td> number_format($RunningTotal,2) </td></tr></table>;
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the data to display in a table format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Print "<TABLE><tr><td width = '50 px'>Responsibility: $<strong></td> ";
Print "<td>".number_format($RunningTotal,2)." </td></tr></table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your second print statement is missing a quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

Use echo, it is faster than print

```
echo "<TABLE><tr><td width = '50 px'>Responsibility: $<strong></td> ";
echo "<td> ".number_format($RunningTotal,2)." </td></tr></table>;
```